# Java SAAJ Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, soap, saaj

I have a basic SOAP service endpoint, actually SAP ECC, presenting a service.  I have tested the service using SOAPUI 4.5, and it works ok using HTTP Auth, preemptive by the looks of things.  I see an outbound "Authorization:Basic BASE64" and the service responds appropriately.

I am now trying to roll this into Java.  I thought that I would take a SAAJ approach with:

```
 SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
 SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
 String url = "http://SAPSERVER:8006/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_lookup_generic_prototype/300/z_user/z_user_binding";
 SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
 SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, url);
```

But I cannot find a way to add the HTTP authentication in.  I believe that SAAJ provides the means to control the SOAP message, but how do I add authentication in?  Are there any alternatives worth considering?

Answer (score 21):

From this page : https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WebServicesHowTo

```
SOAPMessage message = ...
String authorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode((username+":"+password).getBytes());
MimeHeaders hd = message.getMimeHeaders();
hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
```