# How to create soap request in java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to write the following SOAP request in java, but seem to be struggling with how to write referencing the id type element in my request. Does anyone know how to write the following request in java using javax.xml.soap? I'm starting out with a very simple request. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.library/bsvc">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <bsvc:Get_Book_Request>
        <bsvc:Request_References>
            <bsvc:Book_Reference>
                <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="BOOK_ID">25243</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Book_Reference>
        </bsvc:Request_References>
    </bsvc:Get_Book_Request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.library/bsvc">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Get_Book_Request>
            <bsvc:Request_References>
                <bsvc:Book_Reference>
                    <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="BOOK_ID">25243</bsvc:ID>
                </bsvc:Book_Reference>
            </bsvc:Request_References>
        </bsvc:Get_Book_Request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Delete your comment and move the soap request into the body of your question.

Comment: By far the easiest way to make a SOAP request is to generate classes from the WSDL using the [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/wsimport.html) tool that comes with every JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think this SO Q&A might already cover the general setup in building a SOAP message using Java's API:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291283/soap-request-to-webservice-with-java),
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19745299/2356554)