# Send Soap request with Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I never used Soap.
[I searched and found some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291283/soap-request-to-webservice-with-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My goal is to send like this Soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:pay>
     <tem:merchantId>7507231</tem:merchantId>
     <tem:branch>Licensed Branch Name</tem:branch>
     <tem:alias>Service alias Name</tem:alias>
     <tem:paymentId>merchants payment idetificator</tem:paymentId>
     <tem:data>
        <tem:param>
           <tem:key>account</tem:key>
           <tem:value>account cridentials</tem:value>
        </tem:param>
     </tem:data>
     <tem:hash>?</tem:hash>
   </tem:pay>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can send like this Soap request? or give me a examples or tutorials to send a soap like this.
Thanks everyone

Comment: You can use SOAPUI as an IDE to create a SOAP Request and send to the server (or endpoint) - https://www.soapui.org

Comment: I know this is a same question ,but How I can create like this Soap request  ? @Santosh Joshi

Comment: Is it a possible to create java code with this program ?  @Prabin Paudel

Comment: If you have a WSDL. then you can use `WSDL2Java` to generate java code

Comment: Take a look at this - https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/soapui-projects.html#2-1-SOAP-Projects, First you need to make sure that you can consume the service before writing the code (kind of TDD) and then you can write the client. In order to generate client, you can use Eclipse and create project such as Web Service Client in order to generate the Java Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below there's a demo of how you could do it. Basically you call `addChildElement` and `addTextNode` for each element you need.

Make sure **you change the endpoint URL and SOAP Action** in the `main` method before calling.

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    // SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String soapEndpointUrl = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx"; // CHANGE ME
        String soapAction = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit"; // CHANGE ME

        callSoapWebService(soapEndpointUrl, soapAction);
    }

    private static void createSoapEnvelope(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String myNamespace = "tem";
        String myNamespaceURI = "http://tempuri.org/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("pay", myNamespace);

        SOAPElement merchantId = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("merchantId", myNamespace);
        merchantId.addTextNode("7507231");

        SOAPElement branch = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("branch", myNamespace);
        branch.addTextNode("Licensed Branch Name");

        SOAPElement alias = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("alias", myNamespace);
        alias.addTextNode("Service alias Name");

        SOAPElement paymentId = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("paymentId", myNamespace);
        paymentId.addTextNode("merchants payment idetificator");

        SOAPElement data = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("data", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement dataParam = data.addChildElement("param", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement dataParamKey = dataParam.addChildElement("key", myNamespace); dataParamKey.addTextNode("account");
        SOAPElement dataParamValue = dataParam.addChildElement("value", myNamespace); dataParamValue.addTextNode("account cridentials");

        SOAPElement hash = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("hash", myNamespace);
        hash.addTextNode("?");
    }

    private static void callSoapWebService(String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapRequest = createSOAPRequest(soapAction);
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequest, soapEndpointUrl);

            // Print the SOAP Response
            System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
            soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String soapAction) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage);

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message, just for debugging purposes */
        System.out.println("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("\n");

        return soapMessage;
    }

}
```