# Soap version mismatch in java

Tags: java, soap

**Soap-request generated Java application  [Failed]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:dir="http://xxxxxxxxxx">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <xxxxxxxxxxx>       
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Soap-request generated by SoapUI [Successful]**

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
   xmlns:dir="http://xxxxxxxxxx">
 <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
     <dir:ping/>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

How to change namespace uri "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" to "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope". I haven't created any client, i have just created java class and running i'm able to send request and getting faultcode response because of the above uri links. I found it is version mismatch but i dont know how to change.

Comment: Add your java soap client code snippet without it, its hard to answer.

Comment: [Link to code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291283/soap-request-to-webservice-with-java/19745299#19745299)

I have used the same code in the answer shown in this link.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();**  ------ it will give 1.1 version default

change to following to get the 1.2 version of soap namespace

**MessageFactory factory = 
    MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);**

you can find it in SAAJ tutorials

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you must be using the default SOAP implementation(which is SOAP 1.2) as provided into the [Statckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291283/soap-request-to-webservice-with-java/19745299#19745299) question. Your web service may be expecting SOAP 1.1.

If you could change it `SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl` implementation it should solve your problem. Your namespace will changed to `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

Change `callSoapWebService` method first line to following and it should resolve the issue.

`SOAPMessage soapMessage = SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.newInstance().createMessage();`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Change between http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ and http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelop worked fine for me!