# How to send a SOAP request using Java?

Tags: java, soap

I want to send a SOAP WebService request using Java. My Request XML is placed as an xml file at an external location. I would need to access this file and then send it to the webservice endpoint. Also the endpoint url uses the HTTPS protocol so its encrypted using SSL. Finally, after receiving the response successfully, i would like to extract the results and print the response. I'm a beginner in Java and WebService validation, so if someone can provide an understandable solution, it would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291283/soap-request-to-webservice-with-java) can help you reaching your goal.

Comment: Thanks @Jelle for providing this link. The example shared by acdjunior looks interesting. But in the code, he is creating his own soap request whereas i need to access an external request xml file. Also, can you help me understand the difference between actual url and soapAction.